# How to Disable Grid View Row After File Upload Control Completes File Uploading Operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a grid view in which there are three fields. First is data bound field, second is template field contains text box control and third is again template field contains the FileUpload Control.

I want to disable the grid view row when file upload control completes the file upload operation.

My code for grid binding is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class gr4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AMIR-PC\\MOHEMMAD;Initial Catalog=CRM_InvestPlus;Integrated Security=True");
    string query = "Select Capacity from Dealer_License_Capacity where ID='D00001' and Software_ID='001' and Version_ID='1'";
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query,cn);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cn.Close();


    string query1 = "select  Price from Version_Master where Software_ID='001' and Version_ID='1'";
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, cn);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds1);
    cn.Close();


    string query2 = "select Software_Name from Software_Master where Software_ID='001'";
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, cn);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds2);
    cn.Close();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   // dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Software_Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));

    int count = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
     //   dr["Name"] = "aaa";
        dr["Software_Name"] = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        dr["Price"] = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        if (i == 0)

            Response.Write(dr["Price"]);

    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    //GridView1.SelectedRow.Enabled = false;


  }
}
```

And the source file of the Grid is :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Software_Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Data is bounded perfectly but I want to disable the selected row of gridview after the file upload control completes the operation.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when does your file uploading starts ??

Comment: Its just simple operation.

Number of file uploaders are provided based on the capacity

And I have to upload files the numbers which I want. Its not a specific time to upload. When ever the user selects file to upload, it should be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
               e.Row.Enabled=false;//Check on the condition that uploaded is completed            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check using FileUpload1.HasFile if true then the file is uploaded

Comment: I have included both the files .cs and .aspx files

and I have that much of code only .. @isso